# can't get iOS push to work on ad hoc internal testers in iTunes Connect

Tags: ios, xcode, parse-platform, push-notification, app-store-connect

I'm trying to test push notifications for internal testers via iTunes Connect.

This is what I have done:

#### 1. Created an archive with provisioning profile set to ad hoc distribution profile with production push enabled in the app id:

[image]

[image]

#### 1.a I enabled background modes for push:

[image]

#### 2. I uploaded the file to iTunes connect.  Although I cannot choose any other profile than XC:*

[image]

#### 3. I have setup all the relevant push registration methods in the app delegate:

```
//This is never called
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
    //Parse
    // Initialize Parse.
    [Parse setApplicationId:@""
                  clientKey:@""];

    // [Optional] Track statistics around application opens.
    [PFAnalytics trackAppOpenedWithLaunchOptions:launchOptions];



    PFObject *statusObject = [PFObject objectWithClassName:@"StatusObject"];
    statusObject[@"statusMessage"] = @"hit did finish launching";


            UIUserNotificationSettings* notificationSettings = [UIUserNotificationSettings settingsForTypes:UIUserNotificationTypeAlert | UIUserNotificationTypeBadge | UIUserNotificationTypeSound categories:nil];
            [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerUserNotificationSettings:notificationSettings];


    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    return YES;
}

#pragma mark - push methods

- (void)application:(UIApplication*)application didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:(NSData*)deviceToken
{
    //[PFPush storeDeviceToken:deviceToken];
    // Store the deviceToken in the current installation and save it to Parse.
    PFInstallation *currentInstallation = [PFInstallation currentInstallation];
    [currentInstallation addUniqueObject:@"members" forKey:@"channels"];
    [currentInstallation setDeviceTokenFromData:deviceToken];
    [currentInstallation setBadge:0];
    [currentInstallation saveInBackgroundWithBlock:^(BOOL succeeded, NSError *error) {
        if(!error){
            PFObject *statusObject = [PFObject objectWithClassName:@"StatusObject"];
            statusObject[@"statusMessage"] = @"register push worked";
            statusObject[@"token"] = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%",deviceToken];
            [statusObject saveInBackgroundWithBlock:^(BOOL succeeded, NSError *error) {
                if (succeeded) {
                    // The object has been saved.
                } else {
                    // There was a problem, check error.description
                }
            }];
        }else{
            PFObject *statusObject = [PFObject objectWithClassName:@"StatusObject"];
            statusObject[@"statusMessage"] = @"register not successful";
            statusObject[@"token"] = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%",deviceToken];
            statusObject[@"error"] = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%",error];
            [statusObject saveInBackgroundWithBlock:^(BOOL succeeded, NSError *error) {
                if (succeeded) {
                    // The object has been saved.
                } else {
                    // There was a problem, check error.description
                }
            }];
            NSLog(@"Failed to get token, error: %@", error);
        }
    }];

    NSLog(@"My token is: %@", deviceToken);

}

- (void)application:(UIApplication*)application didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError:(NSError*)error
{
    NSLog(@"Failed to get token, error: %@", error);
}

- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo {

    NSLog(@"didReceiveRemoteNotification");

    NSLog(@"push notification user info: %@ ", userInfo);

    if (application.applicationState == UIApplicationStateInactive) {
        [PFAnalytics trackAppOpenedWithRemoteNotificationPayload:userInfo];
    }

    if (application.applicationState == UIApplicationStateActive){

    } else if (application.applicationState == UIApplicationStateBackground){
        NSLog(@"UIApplicationStateBackground");
    } else if (application.applicationState == UIApplicationStateInactive){
        NSLog(@"UIApplicationStateInactive");
    } else {
        NSLog(@"else");
    }

    [PFPush handlePush:userInfo];
}

- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo
fetchCompletionHandler:(void (^)(UIBackgroundFetchResult))completionHandler {
    [PFPush handlePush:userInfo];
    NSLog(@"push notification with handler user info: %@ ", userInfo);

    //    NSLog(@"UIApplicationStateActive");
    //    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]
    //     postNotificationName:@"com.buffernet.totallyfitlife.reportsaved"
    //     object:nil];

    if (application.applicationState == UIApplicationStateInactive) {
        [PFAnalytics trackAppOpenedWithRemoteNotificationPayload:userInfo];
    }
}

- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didRegisterUserNotificationSettings:(UIUserNotificationSettings *)notificationSettings
{
    //register to receive notifications
    [application registerForRemoteNotifications];
}

//For interactive notification only
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application handleActionWithIdentifier:(NSString *)identifier forRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo completionHandler:(void(^)())completionHandler
{
    //handle the actions
    if ([identifier isEqualToString:@"declineAction"]){
    }
    else if ([identifier isEqualToString:@"answerAction"]){
    }
}
```

#### 4. Lastly, I get an email from apple saying:

> Dear developer,
>
> We have discovered one or more issues with your recent delivery for
>   "App". Your delivery was successful, but you may wish to correct the
>   following issues in your next delivery:
>
> Missing Push Notification Entitlement - Your app appears to include
>   API used to register with the Apple Push Notification service, but the
>   app signature's entitlements do not include the "aps-environment"
>   entitlement. If your app uses the Apple Push Notification service,
>   make sure your App ID is enabled for Push Notification in the
>   Provisioning Portal, and resubmit after signing your app with a
>   Distribution provisioning profile that includes the "aps-environment"
>   entitlement. See "Provisioning and Development" in the Local and Push
>   Notification Programming Guide for more information. If your app does
>   not use the Apple Push Notification service, no action is required.
>   You may remove the API from future submissions to stop this warning.
>   If you use a third-party framework, you may need to contact the
>   developer for information on removing the API.
>
> After you’ve corrected the issues, you can use Xcode or Application
>   Loader to upload a new binary to iTunes Connect.
>
> Regards,
>
> The App Store team

What am I doing wrong???

Comment: thanks for the formatting help @Mr Rogers

Comment: What specifically does the email state? Have you troubleshot based off their suggestions in the email?

Comment: I added the full email @soulshined

Comment: Did you make a provisioning profile *specifically for ad-hoc push in this app*?

Comment: @AstroCB I added a screenshot of the provisioning profile I created:  distribution with push enabled.